# Update a model field using model method

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I created a model that allows for courses and supporting info to be uploaded

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

from datetime import datetime

# Create your models here.

class Course(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=400)
  thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
  video = models.FileField(upload_to="videos/")
  notes = models.FileField(upload_to="notes/")
  issued_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
  featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_fresh = models.BooleanField(default=True)

  def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("courses:course_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
  
  def time_passed(self):
    delta = datetime.now().date() - self.issued_at
    print(delta, "today: ", datetime.now().date())
    return delta.days

  def is_fresh_check(self):
    if self.time_passed() >= 1:
      self.is_fresh = False
      return self.is_fresh
```

As you can probably guess, I'm trying to see wether after ONE day or more of uploading the course, it should automatically change the value of 'is_fresh' attricbute to False. However, this isn't the case.

I've also created an apiview to see the Course objects in json

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers 

from .models import Course

class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Course
    fields = ('title', 'description', 'issued_at', 'is_fresh')
  
  def to_representation(self, instance):
    data = super().to_representation(instance)
    data['time_passed'] = instance.time_passed()
    data['is_fresh_check'] = instance.is_fresh_check()
    return data
```

Finally, here's the rendered json for the object:

```
[
    {
        "title": "course_name",
        "description": "course_description",
        "is_fresh": true,
        "time_passed": 1,
        "is_fresh_check": false
    }
]
```

**I don't know why my 'is_fresh_check' method isn't updating the 'is_fresh' value to False after 1 day HAS passed nor do I know how to fix it.**

What to do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call model's `save` method for the changes to be saved in db. Also you don't need to make `is_fresh` a model field (column in db), it's redundant. You can just turn it into a `property` so that you can get its value on the fly, like so:

```
@property
def is_fresh(self):
    delta = datetime.now().date() - self.issued_at
    if delta >= 1:
        return False
    return True
```

and in your view:

```
data['is_fresh_check'] = instance.is_fresh
```

filtering it is a bit more involved since you need to annotate the queryset using `F` and `ExpressionWrapper` to calculate `date_not_fresh` (a day after issue_date) and then filter it for entries less than today's date to get all non-fresh courses:

```
from datetime import timedelta, date
from django.db.models import F, ExpressionWrapper, DateField

Course.objects.annotate(
    date_not_fresh==ExpressionWrapper(
        F('reception_date')+timedelta(days=1), 
        output_field=DateField()
    )
).filter(date_not_fresh__lt=date.today())
```

Comment: Well I tried to change the delta to delta.days >=1 and implemented it…how do I see wether it is fresh or not from the api vuew?

Comment: It also sayd 'bool' object is not callable whenever I try to call the is_fresh property

Comment: @Thorb `is_fresh` will be a property, so don't call it with `()`, call it without like this `instance.is_fresh`

Comment: How would I filter results based of this property?